# SQL result merge side-by-side along with row-wise & column-wise summation appending to result

Tags: sql, teradata

I have 2 SQL queries, and I need to merge them side by side. Also, another requirement is to get column wise and row wise summation as well appended to the result. I tried to achieve at least the first part with CTE written over an UNION but couldn't achieve the desired result. If possible, please suggest if there's another way to achieve it or if it is not even possible.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CUST_TYPE, Sum(A.CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) Over (PARTITION BY A.CUST_TYPE) AS SCV_COMPENSATABLE_BALANCE FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO,  CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO ORDER BY CUST_TYPE) rank1
    FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV
    QUALIFY rank1 = 1
)A;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_BENEFICIARY_FUNDS ) AS BENEFICIARY_FUNDS, Sum( CUST_FNDS_UNDR_DISPT_AMT) AS FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE, Sum( TWENTY_PCT_CUST_DOR_AMT) AS DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC 
FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE;
```

Required pics are attached below for reference.

[image: Query1_Result]

[image: Query2_Result]

[image: Desired_Format]

**UPDATE-30112022**
After taking suggestion from Andrew, I was able to get almost the desired table. I used below query to achieve it. Only thing left is to get the final column "TOTAL FSCS Compensation Limit Utilization". Will that be possible with a CTE perhaps?!

Updated Query:

```
SELECT Q1.*, Q2.BENEFICIARY_FUNDS, Q2.FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE, Q2.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.CUST_TYPE, Sum(A.CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) AS SCV_COMPENSATABLE_BALANCE FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO,  CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO ORDER BY CUST_TYPE) rank1
        FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV
        QUALIFY rank1 = 1
    )A GROUP BY A.CUST_TYPE
    UNION    
    SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum(A.CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) AS SCV_COMPENSATABLE_BALANCE FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO,  CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO ORDER BY CUST_TYPE) rank1
        FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV
        QUALIFY rank1 = 1
    )A
    )Q1 
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT T1.*, T4.FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE, T4.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM
        (SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_BENEFICIARY_FUNDS ) AS BENEFICIARY_FUNDS FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE
        UNION
        SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_BENEFICIARY_FUNDS ) AS BENEFICIARY_FUNDS FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '') T1
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT T2.*, T3.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM
            (SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_FNDS_UNDR_DISPT_AMT) AS FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE
            UNION
            SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_FNDS_UNDR_DISPT_AMT) AS FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '') T2
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( TWENTY_PCT_CUST_DOR_AMT) AS DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE
            UNION
            SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum( TWENTY_PCT_CUST_DOR_AMT) AS DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '') T3
        ON T2.CUST_TYPE=T3.CUST_TYPE) T4
    ON T1.CUST_TYPE=T4.CUST_TYPE
    ) Q2 
ON Q1.CUST_TYPE = Q2.CUST_TYPE ORDER BY Q1.CUST_TYPE;
```

Output looks like this currently
[image: Updated_Result]

**SECOND UPDATE** : I was able to get the desired result after adding another JOIN. Below is the final query and final result. If anyone has any other way to achieve the same, do share.

```
SELECT Q1.*, Q2.BENEFICIARY_FUNDS, Q2.FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE, Q2.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC, (Q1.SCV_COMPENSATABLE_BALANCE+Q2.BENEFICIARY_FUNDS+Q2.FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE+Q2.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC) AS TOTAL_FSCS_COMPENSATION_LIMIT_UTILIZATION FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT A.CUST_TYPE, Sum(A.CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) AS SCV_COMPENSATABLE_BALANCE FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO,  CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO ORDER BY CUST_TYPE) TMP_RANK
                    FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV
                    QUALIFY TMP_RANK = 1
                ) A GROUP BY A.CUST_TYPE
                UNION    
                SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum(A.CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT) AS SCV_COMPENSATABLE_BALANCE FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO,  CUST_COMPENSATABLE_AMT, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY CUST_TYPE, FSA_UNIQUE_REF_NO ORDER BY CUST_TYPE) TMP_RANK
                    FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL_SCV
                    QUALIFY TMP_RANK = 1
                ) A
            ) Q1 
INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT T1.*, T4.FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE, T4.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM
                (SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_BENEFICIARY_FUNDS ) AS BENEFICIARY_FUNDS FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE
                UNION
                SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_BENEFICIARY_FUNDS ) AS BENEFICIARY_FUNDS FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '') T1
            INNER JOIN
                (SELECT T2.*, T3.DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM
                    (SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_FNDS_UNDR_DISPT_AMT) AS FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE
                    UNION
                    SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum( CUST_FNDS_UNDR_DISPT_AMT) AS FUNDS_UNDER_DISPUTE FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '') T2
                INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT CUST_TYPE, Sum( TWENTY_PCT_CUST_DOR_AMT) AS DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '' GROUP BY CUST_TYPE
                    UNION
                    SELECT 'Total' AS CUST_TYPE, Sum( TWENTY_PCT_CUST_DOR_AMT) AS DORMANT_ACCOUNTS_X_20PC FROM ddewd10s.FSCS_LIMIT_UTIL WHERE DUPLICATE_URN = '') T3
                ON T2.CUST_TYPE=T3.CUST_TYPE) T4
            ON T1.CUST_TYPE=T4.CUST_TYPE
            ) Q2 
ON Q1.CUST_TYPE = Q2.CUST_TYPE ORDER BY Q1.CUST_TYPE;
```

[image: FinalResult]

Comment: If I'm following, just make each query a `derived table` and join them on cust_type - `select ... from (<first query>) q1 inner join (<second query>) q2 on q1.cust_type = q2.cust_type`

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I could get the desired result. Now only thing is to figure out how to get the total column-wise and row-wise

Comment: I would handle that in your front end reporting tool.

Comment: All of this modifications are currently handled from front desk UI. Business user doesn't want to "click" the button to generate the report, instead they want it received over mail :)